# Why am I NOT getting an out of bound array error when iterating through it?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

So I set up a simple array and iterate through it. For each element, array[i] is filled with a value of 100. I do i < 4 because obviously array[5] doesn't exist for an array OF FIVE ELEMENTS.

If arrays index at 0, why is the compiler NOT freaking out at me? array[5] shouldn't exist...

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 100;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `i < 4` means the maximum values of `i` is three. `i < 5` means the maximum value of `i` is 4. Which is correct, you never access `array[5]`, so there's no array out of bounds in your code.

Comment: Your code does not go out-of-bounds of the array.  But even if it did, there is no guarantee anything will "freak out" at you.  Going out-of-bounds is undefined behavior, meaning anything could happen.

Comment: I don't understand. array[5] should be evaluated and filled with 100. oh wait, array[5] doesn't exist. why am i not getting an error? and what do you mean by your explanation? @john

Comment: `int array[5];` - 5 elements, valid indexes `0-4`. `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` iterates over indexes `0-4` -- no bounds problem.

Comment: array[4] is correct, then you increment i to 5, then you check i<5 is false, and stop. You never attempt to use i=5 because the for loop exited.

Comment: ***why am i not getting an error?*** 1. because you don't access `array[5]`. 2. because even if you did Undefined Behavior does not mean an error will show.

Comment: @ShahJacob `array[i]` is only out of bounds when `i` is five (or more). `i < 5` prevents `i` from ever getting to five.

Comment: @ShahJacob Your understanding of arrays is good, it's something else you are not getting. Something to do with the order in which statements execute perhaps?

Comment: @ShahJacob the highest possible value of `i` is 4, not 5.

Comment: In your last loop, change to `cout << "array[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << '\n';` Does `i` ever exceed `4`?

Comment: It's an important point that if you want all your errors reported to you, don't use c++. It's designed to let you screw up and go along for the ride. Like drescherjm said.

Comment: @KennyOstrom thank you and everyone wh helped me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i < 5` then it must be `4` or less, meaning the maximum is `array[4]`, which is not out of bounds.

I think you must have confused it with doing `i <= 5` which you also see a lot of.

Comment: This probably makes sense. Are you saying array[5] is never reached because the 5 < 5 condition is false?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that. It runs 5 times when i = 0,1,2,3,4 then the next iteration will set i = 5, so it stops before entering the `for` block again as `5 < 5` returns `false`.

Comment: So <= makes it out of bound. I see. Thank you for helping me and not downvoting me to shit :) I feel confident now

Answer (score 3):

```
int array[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    array[i] = 100;
}
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
int array[5];
array[0] = 100;
array[1] = 100;
array[2] = 100;
array[3] = 100;
array[4] = 100;
```

So there is no array out of bounds in that code.

Comment: So why is array[5] not being accessed?

Comment: Wait i see, it's being 5 < 5 is false so array[5] is never accessed. Would I get an error if I put in 6?

Comment: @ShahJacob The behavior of your program would be undefined if you attempted to read or write the value of `array[5]`.  It may produce an error, it may appear to "work", or it may cause demons to fly out of your nose.

Comment: @ShahJacob You may want to read up on Undefined Behavior: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @ShahJacob "it may cause demons to fly out of your nose." don't be scared, though. Although it could happen, it never happened to me till now.

Answer (score 1):

You are never accessed a[5]. You iterated for a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4] only.So it will not throw any error.In loop condition you have written i<5 not i<=5.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `int array[5];`, the 5 doesn't refer to any indexing.. It refers to number of element. But only at this point... When you declare it. Later on, you can access the array through indices 0-4, which you are doing since you have `i < 5`.

Even if you were to access `array[5]` it's not guaranteed your compiler would freak out... But that's maybe another topic, or?